# request.files is empty from php curl request

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to convert this curl request to php.

```
curl -X POST -F "file=@test_img.jpg" "http://127.0.0.1:5000/FileUploading/UploadImage/"test_img.jpg"
```

This request is working correctly with the following flask-RESTful code

```
class UploadImage(Resource):
def post(self, fname):
    file = request.files['file']
    if file:
        # From flask uploading tutorial
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join("Images/", filename))
        return jsonify({"Path": "Images/" + filename})
    else:
        # return error
        return {'False'}
```

However, the following php curl request returns error 400 as it seems the request.files parameter is empty.

```
$file_name = "test_img.jpg";
$post_data = array(
     "file" =>  "@" . $file_name,
     "type" => 'image/jpg'
);
$ch = curl_init();

debug_to_console(http_build_query($post_data));
$host = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
$url = $host . "/FileUploading/UploadImage/" . $file_name;
debug_to_console($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$file_param = 'file=' . $file_name;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";
debug_to_console($headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    debug_to_console('Error:' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong in this php request

Comment: Step 1: Give us the error-free version of your cURL statement. With `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/FileUploading/UploadImage/"test_img.jpg"` at the end, that can not actually be it.

Comment: Step 2: Tell us what PHP version you are using. The possibility to use `@filename` syntax for file uploads was set to false in default configuration with PHP 5.6, and has been completely removed in PHP 7.

Comment: @04FS the curl statement at the top is error free and the php version is 7.3 what is the equivalent in the latest versions of php?

Comment: How can `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/FileUploading/UploadImage/"test_img.jpg"` be error free? If the inner `"` was supposed to be part of the value, surely it would need to be escaped somehow; and if it is just a normal delimiter, then `test_img.jpg"` on its own after would not make much sense.

Comment: _“and the php version is 7.3 what is the equivalent in the latest versions of php?”_ - https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Comment: @04FS its a string in the cmd and it works. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, don't try to upload files using the `@` method, it was deprecated in PHP 5.5, disabled-by-default in PHP 5.6, and completely removed in PHP 7.0.0, in modern PHP, use [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) to upload files. also in line 10 you don't urlencode $file_name, that's a bug. and in line 17 you're trying to encode it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format (via http_build_query), but the command you're trying to convert is using `multipart/form-data`-format, when you give CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS a string (as returned by http_build_query), curl will send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default but to make curl send it in `multipart/form-data`-format (as you want), set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to an array, not a string, and curl will send it in multipart/form-data.